# Metal // Reading multisampled depth texture

Tags: macos, depth-buffer, metal, compute-shader

For some post-rendering effects I need to read the depth-texture. This works fine as long as multi-sampling is turned off. But with multi-sampling I have trouble reading the texture.

Trying to use the multisample-texture in the shader though an depth2d_ms argument the compiler will fail at run time with an error message "Internal Compiler Error".

I found that with OpenGL you'd first blit the multisample depth buffer to a resolved depth buffer to read the sampled values, but with Metal I get an assertion error stating that sample counts of blit textures need to match, so there is no chance blitting 4 samples into 1.

So how would I read sampled or unsampled values from the depth buffer whilst using multi-sampling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the answer. But suggest to try below solution:

Set the storeAction of MTLRenderPassDepthAttachmentDescriptor as below:

```
  depthAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionMultisampleResolve;
```

and also set its resolveTexture to another texture:

```
  depthAttachment.resolveTexture = targetResolvedDepthTexture.
```

at last, try to read the targetResolvedDepthTexture content.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. It is of course the same procedure as reading a resolved color texture.

Answer (score 0):

MSAA depth resolve is **only supported** in iOS GPU Family 3 v1 (A9 GPU on iOS 9).

Take a look on the Feature Availability document:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/MetalFeatureSetTables/MetalFeatureSetTables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH13-DontLinkElementID_8

Comment: The feature table states that the OS X Family does not support resolving the depth texture but it seems to work. Means I don't get any errors but  I cannot say if the result is 100% accurate though. And still, for devices of older GPU Families, does that mean I have to either give up multisampling or not use depth-buffer dependent shaders?